# No indentation after \paragraph command not working

Tags: indentation, sections-paragraphs

I'm trying to create a new command called `\domanda{}`, that makes use of the `\paragraph{}` to create a series of questions with **Q:** in-built, together with their answers on a *new line*, **WITHOUT** indentation. However this is not giving the expected results. Can you help me find a solution? Please refer to the extensive code below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=3cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfstartview=FitH} %fits pdf to width, FitV= fits pdf to hight
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{marvosym}

\newcommand{\domanda}[1]{\paragraph{Q: #1\newline}}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
 ...   
\begin{document}
\input{somefile.tex} 
\end{document}
```

The new sentence I type after the `\paragraph{}` start on a new line but **WITH** indentation.

Answer (score 4):

Please always post complete minimal documents that show the problem. I have removed the packages not relevant here.

`\paragraph` is a sectioning command, and LaTeX supports two styles of such commands: display and run-in. Run in headings do not invoke the code to suppress paragraph indentation. Placing a forced line break in the heading does not produce the correct effect as you see.

You could redefine `\paragraph` not to be run-in, but then it would be more or less the same as `\subsubsection` so I have just used that here:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 10pt]{article}

\newcommand{\domanda}[1]{\subsubsection*{Q: #1}}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

\domanda{zzz}
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible solution:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}

\newcommand{\domanda}[1]{\paragraph{Q: #1}\mbox{}\par\nobreak\noindent\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}

\domanda{A}
test text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Any thing a little bit simpler? I'm not familiar w/ all those brackets and numbers and symbols... Basically I don't understand why  `\setlength\parindent{0pt}` doesn't work ;)

Comment: @WobbyWindows please see my updated answer.